# Unable to render font awesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4, font-awesome-3.2

I am using following code to render font awesome icons

**Index.html:**  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

On the page: `<p><i class="fa fa-gear fa-5x"></i> fa-gear</p>` **This results in - See below image for result:**

[image]

**But when I change it to** `<p><i class="fa-square-o"></i> fa-gear</p>` when I use class [fa-square-o](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/square-o/) I do not see correct result .See this image

**What needs to be done to fix this issue?**

[image]

Comment: you need to add the 'fa' class to every icons, if its still not showing, may be the icon wasn't present in this version of font awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `fa` class also:

```
<i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Is there any way to change the back color to blue instead of black

Comment: I would do that directly on inline style adding this:
`<i class="fa fa-square-o" style="color:#00f;"></i>`
Just get the correct blue you want and change it.